# How to find if function is bijective analytically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been given the following problem

> "Define $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow(0,1]$ by $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Determine whether or not $f$ is injective and/or surjective"

I don't really just want the answer. I'm just stumped as to how to do this without just going out and graphing it. Is there a way to do it without using a graphing utility? I tried to get the inverse of the function analytically and got $y=\sqrt{-\ln{x}}$

Not sure how to proceed or is it really as simple as typing the original function into desmos and examining the function by eye?

Comment: The existence of an inverse function is a proof that the original function is bijective. Be sure to check that the expression you found for the inverse is well defined and is, indeed, a right and left inverse to $f$

Comment: use $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: It is not. Inverse does not exist. Note that $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{-1^{2}}=e^{-(-1)^{2}}$ so $f$ is not injective. Since every number $x$ in $(0,1]$ is $f(y)$ when  $y =\sqrt {-\ln\, x}$ it follows that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: thanks, $f$ is not injective throughout the entire domain but is it injective within the specified domain $(0,1]$? One of the values you tested for injectivity (i.e., -1) was not in the specified domain in the question

Comment: @esc123 The domain is not $(0,1]$. $f$ is defined as a function from $\mathbb R$ into $(0,1]$. So the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: indeed I was mistaken about stated domain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $e^{-x_1^2}=e^{-x_2^2}$ shows $x_1^2=x_2^2$. this reveals two answer $x_1=x_2$ and $x_1=-x_2$. thus the function isn't injection.

for surjectivity let $b\in(0,1]$ then $\ln b=-x^2$ or $x=\sqrt{-\ln b}$ so it is surjective and existance of this $x$ is sufficient to show that it is onto.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a comment a minute ago but I was actually mistaken about the stated domain. Never mind my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Injectivness is pretty simple: suppose that $\exists x,y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$, then we get:
$e^{-x^{2}}=e^{-y^{2}} \Rightarrow x^{2}=y^{2}$ and by that: $x=\pm y$ so the function is not injective and thus not invertible. If we restrict the dominion on $\bigl(0,1\bigl]$ then we get that $f$ is injective. The expression you have got: 
$$ x=\sqrt{-lny} $$ gives you surjectivness, and so $f$ in bijective and thus invertible. 
Usually it is pretty crucial showing that $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ and in thi case it is not even true if we don't take a restricted dominion. Indeed when you find $x=\sqrt{-lny}$ you have to decide if either $x$ is equal to the square root with a plus sign or a minus sign, which basically says it is not injective on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: good answer. So this function taken over the whole domain is not injective but taken over the domain specified in the question, then over this interval it is injective. I'm not quite getting why we can determine $f$ is surjective given its inverse is $\sqrt{-\ln{x}}$. what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: To find that you just wrote: $y=e^{-x^{2}}$ and by that we get $x=\pm\sqrt{-lny}$, as x runs through $\mathbb{R}$ we can't determine its sign! Once we say: consider the dominion $\bigl(0,1\bigr]$ then we can take the plus sign and so we find a function which is the inverse of $f$